# Symfony3 ugly URL paths after submit (url rewrite or ruting)

Tags: php, search, doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-2.8

I am using:

- Symfony v3.0.6;
- Doctrine v2.5.4

I have built site search with LIKE in the doctrine query.

```
// My search query 
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('i')
    ->from('AppBundle:Item', 'i')
    ->where('i.name_lv LIKE :term')
    ->andWhere('i.description_lv LIKE :term')
    ->setParameter('term', '%' . $term . '%')
    ->orderBy('i.price', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery();
```

It works fine if I write requests manually into the browsers address bar.

For example:

- http://localhost:8000/lv/search/productName
- http://localhost:8000/lv/search/orherProductName

returns page with products that was searched.

### PROBLEM:

Though when I use search button in the form (like every user should)

```
// Relevant part of twig template showing my search form
<div class="search-box row clearfix text-center">
    <form id="search-form" method="GET">
        <fieldset>
            <p>{{ "goods.msg.searchSomething"|trans }}</p>
            <input type="text" class="input-term" name="term" />
            <p>{{ msg }}</p>
            <input type="submit" class="input-submit button small success" value="{{ "goods.button.search"|trans }}" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have problem with paths - because

then I get ugly URLs like these:

- http://localhost:8000/lv/search?term=productName
- http://localhost:8000/lv/search/productName?term=orherProductName

**I suspect, that this might be *URL rewrite* or *routing* problem**

**I need pretty URLs always - not only when manually typing URL, but also when using form to search products.**

Here is relevant code from search controller:

```
// start of function: searchAction
// getting GET parameter
$term = $request->get('term');

// end of function: searchAction
// rendering template with additional parameters 
return $this->render('search/search.html.twig', array(
    'search_items' => $search_items,
    'msg' => '', 
    'term' => $term
));
```

Here is my routing:

```
goods_search_show:
    path: /{_locale}/search-show/{id}/{term}
    defaults: { _controller: 'AppBundle:Search:searchShow', id: 1, term: '' }
    requirements:
        _locale: lv|en|ru
        id: \d+

goods_search_no_term:
    path:     /{_locale}/search
    defaults: { _controller: 'AppBundle:Search:search' }
    requirements:
        _locale: lv|en|ru

goods_search:
    path:     /{_locale}/search/{term}
    defaults: { _controller: 'AppBundle:Search:search', term: '' }
    requirements:
        _locale: lv|en|ru
```

Please advise.
Thank you for your time and knowledge.

### UPDATE 1:

I need to pass GET parameters, because I have two pages: [1] `search` and [2] `searchShow` (that shows detailed view of only one item) and on that page there is link back to page [1] that needs "term" parameter in order to display the search with same parameters

An example:

- On the search page [1] when I press submit button, after writing in search term, I get URL like `http://localhost:8000/en/search?term=productName`
- On the same page with search results list there are some links to details page [2]. Links are made with `path()` function

  ```
  <li><a class="button secondary small" href="{{ path('goods_search_show', {'id': search_item.id, 'term': term}) }}">{{ "goods.button.view"|trans }}</a></li>
  ```

  and produces URL like `http://localhost:8000/en/search-show/162/productName`
- on this page [2] I have to create link back to search page [1] with search parameter `term` that is passed along in link from search page [1]. To do so, I use `path()` function again

  ```
  <li><a class="button secondary small" href="{{ path('goods_search', app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'term': term})) }}">{{ "goods.button.backToList"|trans }}</a></li>
  ```

  and get URL like `http://localhost:8000/en/search/productName`
- Now - following that link I get back to search page [1] with previous search results displaying.
- Then, when trying another search term and pushing submit button I get URL genereated [A] instead of [B] or [C]

  ```
  [A] http://localhost:8000/en/search/productName?term=anotherProductName 
  [B] http://localhost:8000/en/search/anotherProductName
  [C] http://localhost:8000/en/search?term=anotherProductName
  ```
- As you can see from routing - route goes to `goods_search`. Search is performed for `productName`, but`anotherProductName` is completely ignored (in fact `term` is part of the URL twice).

I feel like there must be better solution than using POST or passing `term` in session. Maybe some additional parameters for `.htaccess` file for Apache server could solve bad URL to become nice.

### UPDATE 2:

I took advice from **Alvin Bunk** and implemented form and updated template to use Form widgets instead of basic html.

Unfortunately when I press search instead of nice URL i get this one

```
`http://localhost:8000/ru/search?term=productName&submit=&_token=IvGAvN-nCR40-PKm--rA92AzGXTbI94y2rDCPZxa5D0`
```

and when I change the term to otherProductName I get

```
`http://localhost:8000/ru/search/productName?term=otherProductName&submit=&_token=IvGAvN-nCR40-PKm--rA92AzGXTbI94y2rDCPZxa5D0`
```

So the problem stays the same - meaning `term` is part of the URL twice.

So maybe this question is really routing or URL rewrite problem? (Routing that I use is mentioned in the question and `.htaccess` file is default that ships with Symfony3).

My form

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'search-form'}, 'action': path('goods_search', {'_locale': lang, 'term': term}), 'method': 'GET'}) }}
    <fieldset>
        {{ form_row(form.term, {'name': term, 'attr': {'class': 'input-term'}}) }}
        {{ form_row(form.submit, {'attr': {'class': 'input-submit small success'}}) }}
    </fieldset>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Ths is ItemType

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class ItemType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('term', TextType::class, array('mapped' => false, 'label' => false))
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Test label for SUBMIT button'))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Item',
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is how I create form in `SearchController`

```
$item = new Item();
$form = $this->createForm(ItemType::class, $item);

return $this->render('search/search_show.html.twig', array('term' => $term, 'form' => $form->createView()));
```

### UPDATE 3:

Found a couple workarounds for my problem, after applying both site seems to work as intended.

WORKAROUND 1

Simply omitting form's action attribute makes an URL work and overwrite `term` in the URL instead of displaying it twice.

my form now

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'search-form'}, 'method': 'GET'}) }}
    <fieldset>
        {{ form_row(form.term, {'name': term, 'attr': {'class': 'input-term'}}) }}
        {{ form_row(form.submit, {'attr': {'class': 'input-submit small success'}}) }}
    </fieldset>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

WORKAROUND 2

On the second page there is link back to the search page with `term` in the URL like `search?term=productName`

So in the second search page template I create **custom ugly URL** with this code:

```
{% set link_back = path('goods_search') ~ '?term=' ~ term %}
<li><a href="{{ link_back }}">link back to main search page</a></li>
```

instead of merging `term` with route parameters

```
{% set link_back = path('goods_search', app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'term': term})) %}
<li><a href="{{ link_back }}">link back to main search page</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal to have such URL using GET method, try using POST.

But the best would be to use Ajax.

Comment: I need to pass GET parameters, because I have two pages: [1] search and [2] searchShow (that shows detailed view of only one item) and on that page there is link back to page [1] that needs "term" parameter in order to display the search with same parameters.

Comment: maybe  you can pass that parameters  using  session ?,  this  way or another  - if you using  get  method ,  your  url will be  bad

Comment: Nothing here prevents you from using POST method to get your search params, then render your searchShow, with a back button that redirect on your previous view passing your term as a parameter

Comment: I updated my question to illustrate the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in your twig template:

```
{{ form_start(form, 
    {'action': path('/en/search-show',
        {'id':search_items.getID,
        'term':term}),
    'method': 'GET'}) }}
```

Then, I like to use annotations in my controller (instead of a YAML file) and do something like this to handle the parameters:

```
/**
 * @Route("/search-show/{id}/{term}",
 *  defaults={"id" = 0,"term" = 0},
 *  name="submitPetHasProgram")
 */
public function searchShowAction($id, $term, Request $request){
...
```

Then the URL would look like:
http://localhost:8000/lv/search/someId/someTerm

I show "someId" and "someTerm", but would be the actual id and term passed in coming from the twig template.

Comment: I took your advice (see Update 2 of the question) unfortunately result is still the same - meaning `term` is part of the URL twice.